# knitr with TeXworks

Tags: editors, texworks, knitr

There is a great piece on [Yihui's site](http://yihui.name/knitr/) about [using knitr with TeXShop](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/). Taking some time for some self indulgent curiosity here. Is there a way to use knitr as an engine in TeXworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add knitr as additional engine into TeXworks similar as already shown on [the linked demo page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/) for Texmaker *(note: I do not know knitr at all and also I’m not a regular user of TeXworks, so some mistakes are possible)*:

*Edit:* Yihui added instructions for TeXworks to the already mentioned page [Editors for knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/).

- Open the “Preferences” window (can be found in the “Edit” menu) and go to the “Typesetting” tab.

  <sub>*(For next steps see image below.)*</sub>
- Then (step 1 one the image) add a new Processing Tool. In the new window give it a name (step 2) and add the executable file (step 3). Last add the needed arguments (step 4); you can add more than one by repeated pressing the plus sign. I also marked the TeXworks variable `$basename`, there exists a `$fullname` as well. Press OK.

  <sub>*Edit:* And I **made** a mistake: The arguments must be splitted into two – first argument `-e`, second `knitr::knit2pdf('$basename.$suffix')` (this second changed according to Yihui).</sub>

  [image: Preferences for knitr in TeXworks]

Then you can choose this processing tool in the main window from the menu “Typeset” or from the toolbar popdown:

[image: TeXworks toolbar, choose processing tool]

Comment: I just added the link to this answer in http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/; for some reason I had to put `-e` and `"knitr::knit2pdf(...)"` in two lines under Ubuntu in the arguments; not sure if it has to be the case under Windows as well.

Comment: @Yihui: I think, you are right! As I wrote in the beginning: “… some mistakes are possible”.

Comment: @Yihui BTW: TeXStudio as Texmaker fork should be almost the same, and TeXnicCenter **is** also very similar!

Comment: @Speravir Thanks! I'll try to test TeXnicCenter some day.

Comment: @Yihui: But don’t forget, it’s a Windows program. I don’t know, whether it runs in wine.

Comment: @Speravir I have both Windows and Ubuntu on my laptop. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: How do you embed/mix this rnw code  with other code on a tex file with TexWorks?