# Configuring TeXworks processing tools

Tags: texworks

I am trying to configure `TeXworks` to run the following chains:

1. `latex` with automatic dvi viewer opening
2. `latex+dvips` with automatic ps viewer opening

Essentially, I want to learn how to configure TeXworks to create my own chains of commands possibly with a long list of executables that are usable and commands used within TeXworks. That is, what can go under `Program` and `Arguments`.

For example, from the post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18938/10898 if I want to compile
via `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`, I would need to use

```
-e
$latex='latex -synctex=1'
-e
$dvips='dvips -P pdf -t a4'
-pdfps
$fullname
```

with `latexmk` as the `Program` as shown below:

[image]

When I analyze the `pdfLaTeX` settings its much simple than the one shown above. Any clarifications on how to create these settings and explanation or tutorials to understand TeXworks at this level will be very helpful. Is `latexmk` the only `Program` which can be used? I have tried changing it to `latex.exe` or the sort but no good results.

Comment: Perhaps related/useful: `arara` does helps with this kind of thing

Comment: @cmhughes I have read about arara but haven't implemented its use.

Comment: Maybe, I understand you wrong, but perhaps my answer [knitr with TeXworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85154/knitr-with-texworks/85165#85165) helps a bit?

Comment: BTW from the help menu in TeXworks there is a link to “A short manual for TeXworks”. This ain’t helpful?

Comment: @Speravir Not quite. It contains only basic information about TeXworks and no specifications in creating processing tools.

Comment: The `simpdftex` script can run `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` if called with arguments `latex` and `$fullname`

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest that you create your own batch file doing exactly what you want. I'm not on windows now, but I believe it should look like this:

```
latex -synctex=1 "%1.%2" && dvips -P pdf -t a4 "%1.dvi" && ps2pdf "%1.ps"
```

(The `&&` ensure that the next stages are not executed in the case of an error.) Save it under some unique name like `myldpp.bat` (MY Latex Dvi Ps Pdf) in the folder where TeXworks look for it, e.g. the `./bin/win32` of your `texmf` tree. Finally create a rule in TeXworks that calls `myldpp.bat` with two arguments `$basename`, `$suffix`.

### [The complete list of `$...` arguments to TeXworks](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#Defining_new_typesetting_tools):

```
$synctexoption   expands to "-synctex=1" if your tools support SyncTeX
$fullname        expands to the full name of your root document (e.g. rootfile.tex)
$basename        expands to the name (without ext.) of your root document (e.g. rootfile)
$suffix          expands to the extension of your root document (e.g. tex)
$directory       expands to the absolute path to the directory containing your root document
```

The webpage also suggest slight improvement of the `.bat` file that I incorporated to the answer now.

Comment: I have read a lot about the batch file. What I am also looking for is the specific inputting of the code names such as `$fullname`, `$synctexoption`, etc that TeXworks uses. I want to learn them so that I can create them within TeXworks. Is there a manual or paper that specifies these commands and how to create the processing tools within TeXworks?

Comment: answer edited .

Comment: It would be good if someone can make a documentation about all of this. Like how to create the processing tools within TeXworks and as batch files later.

Comment: @azetina Two things are needed: (1) arara rule for TeXworks (2) good documentation of arara. I believe both of them exist.

Comment: `$fullname` does not give the expected result when it contains spaces, do you know how to fix that? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398024/texworks-issues-with-files-with-spaces

Comment: @Schneider Have you tried `"$fullname"` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some useful information from David Arnold at redwood university. http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/workshops/LatexWorkshop/ConfigureWindows.php

In the Texworks Preferences, Typesetting tab again, under Processing Tools, click the plus sign, then enter the following:

Name: `latex=>dvips=>ps2pdf`
Program: `c:\miktex\miktex\bin\latex-dvips-ps2pdf.bat`
Arguments: `$basename`

Check "View PDF after running". Click OK to finish.
Open Texworks and create a new file. Enter this line:

```
@latex -synctex=1 "%1.tex" && dvips "%1.dvi" && ps2pdf "%1.ps"
```

Save the file as `c:\miktex\miktex\bin\latex-dvips-ps2pdf.bat`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.