# Texworks issues with files with spaces

Tags: windows, texworks

I noticed when my `.tex` file names contain spaces, that TeXworks (on Windows) is having issues when I try to typeset the document.

Even putting the `$fullname` argument in quotes *(like this `"$fullname"`)* doesn't seem to work.

For example when using the file name `Spaces in file name.tex` and my custom `latexmk` tool (chain):
[image]

I get this output:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.

------------
Latexmk: Could not find file [Spaces].
-- Use the -f option to force complete processing.
```

Weirdly enough using the default pdfLaTeX tool (chain) works.

*Note: No difference whether I put `$fullname` in quotes or not*

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Spaces are causing many problems.

Comment: @Bobyandbob yeah, I've noticed. Using `latexmk` from the command line works fine though.

Comment: Maybe an issue on their bug tracker would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where I wrote a batch file which I want to execute from TeXworks, with `$fullname` as a parameter. the batchfile looked like this:

```
someprogram "%1"
```

yet the program failed to find the file when it contains spaces. I solved the problem by using two pairs of quotation marks:

```
someprogram ""%1""
```