# Compile errors in document: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips`

Tags: errors

Preface: I am not good with Latex. Nor do I know the proper formatting for this type of inquiry.

Someone has sent me some source code, and I am getting this error when I try to create the PDF:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.4393 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

Here is part of the preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage[psamsfonts]{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsbsy, upref, wtrench}
\usepackage[dvips, bookmarks, colorlinks=true, plainpages = false,
  citecolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, filecolor =
blue]{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{exercise}{section}
\numberwithin{example}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\input seteps
```

Comment: You are probably meant to run the code in dvi-mode. But that option is obsolete for many years. The other stuff is also a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes_B notes in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542711/compile-error-from-source-code#comment1370751_542711), the error message comes because you are compiling with pdfTeX.

The preamble has indications that this is probably an old document. The old way of compiling LaTeX was to run *latex* (not *pdflatex*) to produce a `dvi` (device independent) file, which was then further processed to produce a pdf if that is what you wanted.

Although that's not often done nowadays, you can still do it! Run `latex` (not `pdflatex`) which will produce a file ending `.dvi`, then `dvips` on that file (producing a file called `.ps`, then `ps2pdf`, or run `latex` then `dvipdfm`. My preference was usually for the longer route.

The alternative is to try to re-edit the file you have to be processable by `pdflatex`, for instance by removing the particular option to `hyperref` which is telling it to us `dvips`. However, if it's an old document there are probably other ways it expects the `dvips` method, and you may well find it easier to go that way. Whether you get other errors caused by the use of archaic syntax it's not possible to say, though *most* long-standing packages do try to preserve backward compatibility, so you may be OK.

Comment: Paul, any specific instructions for this in TexWorks? I really don't know what any of this means.

Comment: I don't use it but this looks as if it might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85417/configuring-texworks-processing-tools