# Using knitr with TeXworks

Tags: editors, texworks, knitr

I checked out the conversation between Speravir and Yihui, and also Yihui's site and video for getting knitr to work with TeXworks. However, I am definitely not super tech-savvy and I'm having some issues. I went through all the steps in TeXworks to add knitr, but I'm confused about what my .exe file should be, and also what the basename.rnw file should be. I think what I've entered is incorrect and is the cause of the error I'm getting when I compile in TeXworks: Overfull \hbox... Can you please provide more detail? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what you have said above, I suspect the first error is a case error.

The extension must be `Rnw' and not`rnw`  This is not optional.   I presume you have set up as discussed by [knitr with TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85154/knitr-with-texworks) in Speravir's answer with is consistent with Yihui's instructions. http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/

You need to test the setup with a minimal `*.Rnw` file.  As follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test of Knitr setup for editor

<<>>=
2+2
@

and test for base graphics

<<>>=
plot(1:10)
@

\end{document}
```

Save the above as `testknitr.Rnw' and have in the main window of TexWorks.

In TexWorks, select the `knitr` option from the tools menu.

Next select `pgflatex`

And finally select the view pdf option.

You should see: 
[image]